# Race time list and winning time

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

Store the times into arrays called Chevy[ ] and Ford[ ]. Then list the winner of each pair, giving the number of seconds the winner won by. At the end declare which team won based on which team had the most wins.

I have the lists made but I'm not sure how to make it so that I can take the times form the list to show how much each racer won by. For instance the first ford time compared to the first Chevy time and the winner of the race to include ties. And then the overall winner of all the races. So if Chevy won 3 races and ford won 4 races then Ford would be the overall winner.

```
Chevy = []
Ford = []

#this code works so far but the ford loop starts again.
for i in range(8):
    time = float(input("Enter Chevy race time's: "))
    Chevy.append(time)   
    total = 0
    slowest_chevy = Chevy[0]
    fastest_chevy = Chevy[0]
for c in Chevy:
    total = total + c
    if c > slowest_chevy:
        slowest_chevy = c
    if c < fastest_chevy:
        fastest_chevy = c
    print(" The race time's are ",Chevy)
    print("The fastest Chevy time is ",fastest_chevy)
    for j in range(8):
        time = float(input("Enter Ford race time's: "))
        Ford.append(time)   
        total = 0
        slowest_F = Ford[0]
        fastest_F = Ford[0]
    for f in Ford:
        total = total + f
        if f > slowest_F:
            slowest_F = f
        if f < fastest_F:
            fastest_F = f
    print(" The race time's are ",Ford)
    print("The fastest Ford time is ",fastest_F)

def find_winner()#not sure what to put here!
```

Example of what I'm trying to input, and the results.

```
---Input Chevy Times---
Enter time for Chevy Car 1: 5.4
Enter time for Chevy Car 2: 7.2
Enter time for Chevy Car 3: 4.0
Enter time for Chevy Car 4: 9.1
Enter time for Chevy Car 5: 5.8
Enter time for Chevy Car 6: 3.9
Enter time for Chevy Car 7: 6.2
Enter time for Chevy Car 8: 8.1
---Input Ford Times---
Enter time for Ford Car 1: 5.8
Enter time for Ford Car 2: 6.9
Enter time for Ford Car 3: 3.9
Enter time for Ford Car 4: 9.2
Enter time for Ford Car 5: 5.8
Enter time for Ford Car 6: 3.8
Enter time for Ford Car 7: 6.0
Enter time for Ford Car 8: 8.5

#results
And the winners are:
Chevy by 0.4 sec
Ford by 0.3 sec
Ford by 0.1 sec
Chevy by 0.1 sec
Tie!
Ford by 0.1 sec
Ford by 0.2 sec
Chevy by 0.4 sec
And the winning team is: F O R D !
```

Comment: You are looking for `zip`.

Comment: no I don't have a zip file

Comment: I haven’t learned how to use the zip yet